# Is this statement valid in Python?

Tags: python

I am learning to create games using pygame. There is a sample code that creates a surface as follows:

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400
speed = [-2,1]
bg = (255,255,255)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Peppa Pig")
turtle = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\xfeng\Pictures\Saved Pictures\peppa pig.jpg")
position = turtle.get_rect()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    position = position.move(speed)
    if position.left < 0 or position.right > width:
        turtle = pygame.transform.flip(turtle,True,False)
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if position.top < 0 or position.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.fill(bg)
    screen.blit(turtle,position)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(10)
```

The `size = width, height = 600, 400` caught my eye. I know it is used to set the size of the surface on which I am going to run my game. But is this statement valid in Python, or is it only valid for pygame?

Comment: It is definitely valid. What it does is actually create two variable named width = 600 and height = 400 and then create another tuple size which store (600, 400).

Comment: What did python interpreter tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a valid statement. What happens is that if you assign more than one value to a variable, it will create a tuple with the values. In that case, if you print size it would output `(600, 400)`

```py
# If you remove all the syntactic sugar, what you are doing is this:
width = 600
height = 400
size = (width, height)

# But you can create the variables in the same line
width, height = 600, 400
# Then assign it to size
size = width, height # is the same as saying size = (width, height)

# Then you can just put it all to the same line
size = width, height = 600, 400
```

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a valid python expression it will create a tuple with those variable :

```
height = 600, 400
type(height)#<type 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is valid for python. You can assign several values to several variables with one line. It is equivalent to see data as a tuple.

```py
#Your sintax
x,y = 10, 20

#is equivalent
(x,y) = (10,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you get three variables, two ints and one tupel:

```
heigth = {int}400
size = {tuple: 2}(600, 400)
width = {int}600
```

to access the values from size use:

```
>>> size[0]
600
>>> size[1]
400
```